# How to mock third party static method

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

In order to simplify my question, consider the following code:
How do you write test for function `foo1` with patching\mocking the `S3Downloader.read_file` part?

I prefer you will show me example usage of `pytest-mock` or even `unitest.mock`

```
from sagemaker.s3 import S3Downloader

class Fooer(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo1(s3_location):       
        s3_content = S3Downloader.read_file(s3_location)
        return Fooer.foo2(s3_content)


    @staticmethod
    def foo2(s3_content):
       return s3_content +"_end"
```

Comment: foo1 always returns `None`

Comment: @Pynchia: thanks, I corrected it now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note:** Assuming that the snippet you mentioned is in fooer.py file

Please find the following sample test case to test foo1

```
import fooer
import mock

class TestFooer(object):

    @mock.patch('fooer.S3Downloader', autospec=True)
    def test_foo1(self, mock_s3_downloader):
        """
        Verify foo1 method that it should return the content downloaded from S3 bucket with _end prefix
        """
        mock_s3_downloader.read_file.return_value = "s3_content"
        foo1_result = fooer.Fooer.foo1("s3_location")
        assert foo1_result == "s3_content_end", "Content was not returned with _end prefix"
```

In the snippet I have patched fooer.Session class.
To patch an class, we need to provide module & the property of that module.
The mock object is passed to the test case using an argument. You can use that object to modify the behaviour. In this case, I have updated the return value of the S3Downloader.

`autospec=True` in patch verifies that all the specifications of the patched class are properly followed. Basically it checks that the patch object was provided with the correct arguments.

reference: https://medium.com/@yeraydiazdiaz/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832

A very good blog about testing with mock: https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python